# Kotlin Safe Cast Unrecognised with Property Access Syntax

Tags: kotlin, casting, compiler-errors, null, javafx-8

I am using JavaFX and have a modified property as follows to ensure that null is never returned for a list.

```
class BaseListProperty<T>(): SimpleObjectProperty<List<T>>() {

    override fun setValue(value: List<T>?) {
        super.setValue(value ?: listOf())
    }

    override fun getValue(): List<T> {
        return super.getValue() ?: listOf()
    }

}
```

In another class, I have a function that set table cell value and the problem occurs.

```
override fun setCellValue(columnId: String, newValue: Any?) {
    when (columnId) {
        // This is OK as expected
        id -> property.setValue(newValue as? List<SomeClass>)
        // Both below throws "Type Mismatch" Error
        // Required: List<SomeClass>
        // Found: List<SomeClass>?
        id -> property.value = newValue as? List<SomeClass>
        id -> property.value = newValue as List<SomeClass>?
    }
}
```

Since I have defined `setValue` to receive null, why is it throwing compiler error when using property access syntax, but not when using the original function? I am using latest Kotlin `1.3.50`. Thank you.

Comment: If getter and setter type mismatch it cannot be properly converted into a property. Both must either set/return a nullable or non-null.

Comment: @Pawel, you are right. After I changed to `getValue(): List<T>?`, property access syntax is not giving compiler error anymore. I guess I have to use the function call then. Can you please write this as an answer? Thanks!